# Netlogo: How to set different colors to turtles?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

A quick question:

How to set every turtles different colors?

Like, I'd to set the random color whose value ends in *6 or *3 to turtles.

My code:

```
ask  turtles [set color ((random 14) * 10 + 6 ) or ((random 14) * 10 + 3 ))]
```

But it doesn't work. Since the `or` here is wrong.

Is there any other methods express `or` here?

I appreciate any kinds of help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` is a logical test. What you want is to assign `one-of` those values. I think this is what you want:

```
ask  turtles
[ set color one-of (list ((random 14) * 10 + 6 ) ((random 14) * 10 + 3 )) ) 
]
```

Comment: Thank you JenB! Yes I think `one-of` appears to make sense. But `random` in your code triggers an "expected literal value" warning. Also, I think `one-of` requires a list as input, but `random X` is a number. I revised a bit as `ask  turtles[set color one-of [list((random 14) * 10 + 6 ) ((random 14) * 10 + 3 ))     ] ], but it doesn't work either. Maybe do you have any ideas how to change it? Thanks!

Comment: try the revision - i made the list explicit rather than rely on the [ ] syntax